# 2D histogram plot from data file

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

How can you make a 2d histogram (or surface) plot out of a given 2d numpy array where the first index is the label for the 'x' dimension, the 2nd index for the 'y' dimension and the third is the value to be plotted? Example:

```
[[4.80000e+01 5.12000e+02 8.03447e+03]
 [4.80000e+01 2.56000e+02 9.24963e+03]
 [4.80000e+01 1.28000e+02 9.02154e+03]
 [4.80000e+01 6.40000e+01 8.96437e+03]
 [4.80000e+01 3.20000e+01 7.98477e+03]
 [4.80000e+01 1.60000e+01 1.07688e+04]
 [4.80000e+01 8.00000e+00 1.96227e+04]
 [4.80000e+01 4.00000e+00 3.51944e+04]
 [5.20000e+01 5.12000e+02 7.53994e+03]
 [5.20000e+01 2.56000e+02 7.54521e+03]
 [5.20000e+01 1.28000e+02 8.12631e+03]
 [5.20000e+01 6.40000e+01 8.12542e+03]
 [5.20000e+01 3.20000e+01 7.49664e+03]
 [5.20000e+01 1.60000e+01 9.92450e+03]
 ...
```

The whole 2d area to be plotted is (18,8).

Since matplotlib seems to accept the data in a 2d array (meshgrid/contour) I was trying to first stuff the values into a newly created 2d numpy array with a loop but failed at getting the indices looked up. Like

```
xlu=np.unique(d[:,0])
ylu=np.unique(d[:,1])

z=np.empty((xdim,ydim))

for x in d:
    z[ np.where(xlu==x[0])[0] , np.where(ylu==x[1])[0] ] = z[2]
```

Is there a quicker/more elegant way to do get to a 2d histogram/surface plot?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the `hist2d` or `hexbin` functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.tricontourf(d[:,0], d[:,1], d[:,2])` creates filled contours from `x`, `y` and `z` data which aren't organised as a grid.

`plt.hist2d(d[:,0], d[:,1], weights=d[:,2])` creates a 2d histogram where the weight of each `x,y` is given by `z`.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

d = np.random.randn(1000, 10, 3).cumsum(axis=0).reshape(-1, 3)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 4))

sm1 = ax1.tricontourf(d[:, 0], d[:, 1], d[:, 2], cmap='hot')
plt.colorbar(sm1, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('plt.tricontourf()')

_, _, _, sm2 = ax2.hist2d(d[:, 0], d[:, 1], weights=d[:, 2], bins=40, cmap='hot')
ax2.set_title('plt.hist2d()')
plt.colorbar(sm2, ax=ax2)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to interpolate your data since it is irregularly spaced.

Here is a snippet from official documentation ([link](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/irregulardatagrid.html)).

```
import matplotlib.tri as tri
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(19680801)
npts = 200
ngridx = 100
ngridy = 200
x = np.random.uniform(-2, 2, npts)
y = np.random.uniform(-2, 2, npts)
z = x * np.exp(-x**2 - y**2)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

# -----------------------
# Interpolation on a grid
# -----------------------
# A contour plot of irregularly spaced data coordinates
# via interpolation on a grid.

# Create grid values first.
xi = np.linspace(-2.1, 2.1, ngridx)
yi = np.linspace(-2.1, 2.1, ngridy)

# Linearly interpolate the data (x, y) on a grid defined by (xi, yi).
triang = tri.Triangulation(x, y)
interpolator = tri.LinearTriInterpolator(triang, z)
Xi, Yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
zi = interpolator(Xi, Yi)

# Note that scipy.interpolate provides means to interpolate data on a grid
# as well. The following would be an alternative to the four lines above:
#from scipy.interpolate import griddata
#zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='linear')

ax1.contour(xi, yi, zi, levels=14, linewidths=0.5, colors='k')
```

What it essentially does, it interpolates the values of your function to a regular grid using trilinear interpolation. There are other ways to do it depending on your goals.